# Create a P6 XML file using MPXJ java library

Tags: mpxj

I have a json having all the information of my project, its activities, dependencies / relationships and the calendar. Using the MPXJ java library am trying to generate a corresponding Primevera P6 XML file that can be imported in Oracle primevera. I have been successful in creating an xml but when I import it in P6 it is giving me the below error.

*Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializeException: An exception occurred while initializing module 'CommandLineModule'.

- The exception message was: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
- The Assembly that the module was trying to be loaded from was:
  Primavera.Mercury.CommandLineModule, Version=15.2.0.15383, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
  Check the InnerException property of the exception for more information. If the exception occurred while creating an object in a DI container, you can exception.GetRootException() to help locate the root cause of the problem.

---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Primavera.Mercury.Importer.ImportCleaner.CleanupActivities(EntityContext sourceContext)
   at Primavera.Mercury.Importer.ImportCleaner.CleanSourceContext(EntityContext sourceContext, IVenusDataServiceContext targetContext, ILoggerFacade logger, ImportProjectSettings importProjectSettings, Dictionary`2 initialKeyDictionary)
   at Primavera.Mercury.CommandLineModule.ExecuteImportExport.DoImport()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.Initialize(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Failed to load type for module CommandLineModule. 
Error was: An exception occurred while initializing module 'CommandLineModule'. 
    - The exception message was: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    - The Assembly that the module was trying to be loaded from was:Primavera.Mercury.CommandLineModule, Version=15.2.0.15383, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Check the InnerException property of the exception for more information. If the exception occurred while creating an object in a DI container, you can exception.GetRootException() to help locate the root cause of the problem.*

Comment: I'm not sure there is enough here to diagnose the issue. You could try to create simplest possible file containing a minimal amount of data and import that, then gradually add in more data until you get the failure. That might help you to isolate it. Also I'm happy to look at the file to see if I can see anything obvious... if you can make it available for download somewhere.

Comment: @JonIles thank you for the response. I will make it available to you.

Comment: @JonIles this is the xml am trying to import to P6 Primevera. Any help will be much appreciated. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8MnBMS6s1G7RUxrNWFOZEE3LVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Patruni, I've tried importing the file you provided into Primavera P6 R8.4, and it works fine. What version of Primavera are you using?

Comment: @JonIles Thank you for trying it out. Am using Primavera P6 R15.2 version.